# Creating a new column by reading json strings with inconsistent schema in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe in which the important information is stored in a column as json strings that have a similar, but inconsistent schema. Three questions arise from my issue, walked through below:

1. To flatten a dataframe with a json string column, should one create a new column of structs and use `explode`
2. Do UDFs pass individual cell values to the function they wraps?
3. How can I load json arrays of varying length and fields per entry into a single column?

---

This is happening in both databricks and a local install of pyspark.

A MWA of this table can be generated by this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *

jstring_A = """[
{"a_id":"0001","a_s":"apple","score":1},
{"a_id":"0002","a_s":"banana","score":1},
{"a_id":"0003","a_s":"carrot","score":1}
]""".replace('\n','')
# This has 3 responses, each of the fields ["a_id", "a_s", "score"]

jstring_B = """[
{"a_id":"so1","a_R":"aardvark","score":5},
{"a_id":"so2","a_R":"baboon","score":9}
]""".replace('\n','')
# This has 2 responses, each of the fields ["a_id", "a_R", "score"]

data = [(1, jstring_A), (2, jstring_B)]
columns = ["_oid", "json_str"]
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
```

which generates this table

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_oid|json_str                                                                                                                   |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |[{"a_id":"0001","a_s":"apple","score":1},{"a_id":"0002","a_s":"banana","score":1},{"a_id":"0003","a_s":"carrot","score":1}]|
|2   |[{"a_id":"so1","a_R":"aardvark","score":5},{"a_id":"so2","a_R":"baboon","score":9}]                                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

my ultimate goal is to flatten this dataframe. My understanding of the best way to do this is to convert the string to a `struct` inside the dataframe and then use `explode`. This would create 5 rows (one per response), each with columns `_oid, json_str, a_id, a_s, a_R, score`.

**Is this process correct?**

In an effort to flatten, I found [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683915/unify-schema-across-multiple-rows-of-json-strings-in-spark-dataframe) which provided the way to get all the field names in a schema. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083873/spark-2-0-0-reading-json-data-with-variable-schema) explained that any schema fields missing values would simply be loaded as `Null`.

This produces the following code

```
all_fields = spark.read.json(source_df.select("json_str").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).schema
```

and resulting schema

```
StructType(List(StructField(a_R,StringType,true),StructField(a_id,StringType,true),StructField(a_s,StringType,true),StructField(score,LongType,true)))
```

At this point, our questions diverge, as there are a variable number of responses in each json object here, so we cannot simply use that schema. Because the schemas for the column are not constant, we therefore cannot pass [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) a column. However, it can be passed a string.

For this, I resorted to using `.withColumn` and udf.

```
import json as pj

def create_struct(json_str):
  n_responses = len(pj.loads(json_str))
  schema = StructType(
              [StructField(
                            name = f"{i}",
                            dataType= all_fields,
                            nullable= True
                          )
               for i in range(n_responses)]
  )
  return(from_json(json_str,schema))
  
json_as_struct = udf(lambda z: create_struct(z))

new_df = source_df.withColumn("as_struct", json_as_struct(col("json_str")))
```

per my understanding of UDFs, spark will distribute the iteration here and create the column `as_struct` cell by cell by passing the corresponding value of `json_str` to the UDF. **Is this how UDFs work?**

The first sign of error from this code is `new_df`. Before evaluation its schema is

```
DataFrame[_oid: bigint, json_str: string, as_struct: string]
```

as one would expect given the default return type on UDFs is `string`.

When an action call (`new_df.display()`) is made the real error occurs:

```
PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'', from <command-124...>, line 17. Full traceback below:
```

Full traceback is below.

This leads to my last question:
**Can I use a UDF to transform these json strings to structs, and if so what changed should I make to my code for it to function?**

---

Full traceback:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2033.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 2033.0 (TID 32875, 10.60.162.7, executor 167): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'', from <command-124...>, line 17. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 654, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 646, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 231, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 145, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 220, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 467, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 467, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-124...>", line 19, in <lambda>
  File "<command-124...>", line 17, in create_struct
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 2412, in from_json
    jc = sc._jvm.functions.from_json(_to_java_column(col), schema, _options_to_str(options))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2519)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2466)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2668)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2656)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:2985)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3709)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3707)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:2984)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:194)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocal.scala:1158)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1(PythonDriverLocal.scala:1070)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:857)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.getResultBufferInternal(PythonDriverLocal.scala:939)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.getResultBuffer(DriverLocal.scala:538)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.outputSuccess(PythonDriverLocal.scala:899)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$8(PythonDriverLocal.scala:384)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:857)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.repl(PythonDriverLocal.scala:371)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$10(DriverLocal.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:239)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:234)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:231)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:276)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:269)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:408)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:645)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:486)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:598)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:391)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'', from <command-124...>, line 17. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 654, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 646, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 231, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 145, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 220, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 467, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 467, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-124...>", line 19, in <lambda>
  File "<command-124...>", line 17, in create_struct
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 2412, in from_json
    jc = sc._jvm.functions.from_json(_to_java_column(col), schema, _options_to_str(options))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A senior dev came up with the following solution for me:

1. No, one can use `regexp_replace` in conjunction with `functools.reduce` to explode directly from the json string.
2. Did not discuss
3. The following code achieves the desired results:

```
def explode_col(source_df, colname):
  
  keys = spark.read.json(source_df.select(colname).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).columns
  
  source_df = source_df\
    .withColumn("json_trimmed", f.regexp_replace(f.col(colname),'\[|\]', ''))\
    .withColumn("json_trimmed", f.regexp_replace(f.col("json_trimmed"),'\"', ''))\
    .withColumn("json_rep", f.regexp_replace(f.col("json_trimmed"), '\},\{', '\}.\{'))\
    .withColumn("json_array", f.split(f.col("json_rep"), '\.'))\
    .withColumn('exploded', f.explode('json_array'))
  
  pat = "(?<=%s:)\w+(?=(,|}))"
  from functools import reduce
  exploded_col_df = reduce(
      lambda df, c: df.withColumn(
          c,
          f.when(
              f.col("exploded").rlike(pat%c),
              f.regexp_extract("exploded", pat%c, 0)
          )
      ),
      keys,
      source_df
  )
  return(exploded_col_df.drop(colname, "json_trimmed", "json_rep", "json_array", "exploded"))
                
explode_col(source_df, "json_str").show(truncate = False)
```

Comment: I don't think you should listen to your "senior dev"... I would strongly advise against parsing JSON using a regex... Ideally, you should parse the JSON into a struct (inferring the schema or specifying it) and then explode it. If you really want to do it "dynamically", you'd better use Spark JSON functions.